# Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property '$createElement' of undefined"

Tags: html, vue.js

I have a problem with very simple input/output code.
I am supposed to get a input in Newick format and then use this to create a tree.
But I am nowhere close to even getting input right.

Here is my HTML code

```html
<body class="sidebarBody">
  <div class="inputDiv">
    <div class="inputText">
      <textarea v-model="newick" class="newickIn" placeholder="Newick Format"></textarea>
    </div>
    <br />
    <button @click="render()">Render</button>
    <p>{{newick}}</p>
    <p>{{wtf}}</p>
  </div>
</body>
</template>
```

Here is my JavaScript code

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "Sidebar",
  data() {
    return {
      newick: "",
      wtf: "wtf"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    render() {
      this.wtf = this.newick;
      console.log(this.newick);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I used wtf as my debugger but even that did not helped me to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here are the errors:

Error1

```
    vue.esm.js?efeb:628 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property '$createElement' of undefined"

    found in

    ---> <Sidebar> at src/components/Sidebar.vue  
           <Main> at src/components/Main.vue  
             <App> at src/App.vue  
               <Root>
```

Error 2

```
    vue.esm.js?efeb:1897 TypeError: Cannot read property '$createElement' of undefined
    at render (eval at ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler/index.js?{"id":"data-v-7d622f5c","hasScoped":false,"transformToRequire":{"video":["src","poster"],"source":"src","img":"src","image":"xlink:href"},"buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/components/Sidebar.vue (0.84f365116a0d985da83b.hot-update.js:14), <anonymous>:3:16)
    at click (eval at ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler/index.js?{"id":"data-v-7d622f5c","hasScoped":false,"transformToRequire":{"video":["src","poster"],"source":"src","img":"src","image":"xlink:href"},"buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/components/Sidebar.vue (0.84f365116a0d985da83b.hot-update.js:14), <anonymous>:38:22)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.esm.js?efeb:1863)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (vue.esm.js?efeb:2188)
    at HTMLButtonElement.original._wrapper (vue.esm.js?efeb:7559)
```

***So my problem here is that even though (in my opinion) I used @click right and created a method in right order, the code has error about how my newick model is undefined. I tried a real simple example for using vue binding and method usage (which is below) and that worked so I really do not know that is wrong with my code.***

```html
    <div class="tree">
        <button @click="counter()">Count</button>
        <p>{{count}}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Visualization",
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    counter(){
      this.count++;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, name `render()` function differently. It's reserved name since Vue component uses this one to render your template.

Second thing, pass to event only name of the method:

```
    <button @click="display">Render</button>
```

And it should work :)

Comment: Thank you very much, seems like the problem was the name ```render()``` once I changed it, no more problems. Though, I'm new to VueJs but I haven't seen a problem and/or difference between ```name``` and ```name()``` while passing. It's an old habit and I like to put parenthesis afrer method names.